# AOSP repo sync fails on macOS Catalina

Tags: android, macos, android-source, macos-catalina, repo

I keep having the same error while trying to do checkout AOSP source on macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Followed all the instructions on https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing#setting-up-a-mac-os-x-build-environment, also https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading and tried different tags. This is what happens after I invoke  `repo --trace sync -j1`.

```
: git config --file /Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/projects/external/skqp.git/config --includes --null --list 1>| 2>|

: export GIT_DIR=/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/projects/external/skqp.git
: git rev-parse --verify refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r41^0 1>| 2>|

: cd /Volumes/android/aosp/external/skqp
: git read-tree --reset -u -v HEAD 1>| 2>|
error: RPC failed; HTTP 499 curl 16 Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: Cannot checkout platform/external/skqp: GitError: Cannot initialize work tree for platform/external/skqp
: git rev-list refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r41 -1 1>| 2>|
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 630, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 604, in _Main
    result = run()
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 597, in <lambda>
    run = lambda: repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 266, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 983, in Execute
    self._Checkout(all_projects, opt, err_event, err_results)
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 567, in _Checkout
    self._CheckoutWorker(**kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 447, in _CheckoutWorker
    return self._CheckoutOne(opt, project, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 481, in _CheckoutOne
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1223, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync, submodules=submodules)
  File "/Volumes/android/aosp/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2758, in _InitWorkTree
    raise GitError('Cannot initialize work tree for ' + self.name)
error.GitError: Cannot initialize work tree for platform/external/skqp
```